# Why won't my wordpress query work? Custom post types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I can't get this to show posts from my custom post type named "resources." Any help?

```
<?php 
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_post_type_to_query' );
    function add_custom_post_type_to_query( $query ) {
        if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'resources' ) );
        return $query;
    }
?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
<?php else : ?>
```

Comment: Did you put the `add_custom_post_type_to_query` stuff in your template? It should reside in your `functions.php` file

Answer (score 0):

This part should go into functions.php :

```
<?php 
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_post_type_to_query' );
    function add_custom_post_type_to_query( $query ) {
        if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'resources' ) );
        return $query;
    }
?>
```

while this part is in template file :

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
<?php else : ?>
```

Explanation :

The 1st part is activating a filter / action  on `pre_get_posts()` . but when you put it inside a theme file or template file , the filter will fire too late or not fire at all.

Your `functions.php` file in a theme is the first one to be parsed, and therefore it should  contain all the functions that are not DIRECTLY related to rendering or visualization of the page .

The `loop` however, which is a rendering mechanism, should be in the appropriate theme file.